# icon of the web page

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Как поставить вот такую иконку сайта? Как это работает?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSXqU.jpg

Comment: Чтоб сделать для всех браузеров и платформ, можете сгенерировать иконки через сайт https://realfavicongenerator.net/ так как некоторые браузеры фавиконы не только 16х16 в формате ico принимают а и [svg](https://caniuse.com/link-icon-svg) (векторные) и png, по этому можете нарисовать векторную svg и сгенерировать через сайт для всех остальных

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скачайте/нарисуйте картинку в размере 16х16 px и сохраните в нужном вам месте.
После в шапке сайта пропишите следующее:

```
<head>
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
```

Где:
rel ="..." указатель что изменяете, в данном случае - иконку сайта.
href - путь до картинки (можно заменить ссылкой на картинку, если не скачивали, а брали из интернета, погуглите разницу).
type - тип используемого изображения (формат)

Желательно использовать формат картинки ico, но так же допускается GIF и PNG
При изменении на другой формат, нужно указать новый тип  image/gif или image/png в зависимости от того что используете

Точно, а сам тег link нужен для того чтобы указать что вы собираетесь использовать что-то. Будь то иконка, файлы стилей css, title сайта и тому подобные вещи